# Android jetpack compose change scaffold background color not changing

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Hello I am sorry if I break some rules. But I have tryed to search for a solution both here, and with google. The solutions I find don't seem to work

I want to change the background color of a scaffold composable function in android jetpack compose

Here is my code. I simply don't understand how come when I run the app, the background color remains to be white, even i specify it to be my own custom color ?

As you can see i tryed to change it both with a modifier, and with the backgroundColor parameter.

```
Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(AppColors.mOrangeOne),
        topBar = { TopBar() },
        floatingActionButton = { FAB() },
        backgroundColor = AppColors.mOrangeOne
    )
```

```
object AppColors {
    val mLightGray = Color(0xffb4b9cd)
    val mBlack = Color(0xff060814)
    val mOffWhite = Color(0xffeceeef)
    val mLightPurple = Color(0xff545a75)
    val mDarkPurple = Color(0xff262C49)
    val mOffDarkPurple = Color(0xFF22496B)
    val mLightBlue = Color(0xff127EEA)
    val mBrown = Color(0xff7f6749)
    val mBlue  = Color(0xff4b5f9e)
    val mOrange  = Color(0xFFFF9800)
    val mOrangeOne  = Color(0xffFFD54F)
    val mOrangeTwo  = Color(0xffFFCA28)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `backgroundColor` param works. But if `Scaffold`'s content is defining a background, it will overlap the `Scaffold` background...

1. If you set the `Surface` color, but not set the `Scaffold`'s `backgroundColor` nor content background like below...

```
setContent {
    YourAppTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = Color.Red
        ) { 
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The background will be red.

2. If you set the `Scaffold` background but not set the content's background like below...

```
setContent {
    YourAppTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = Color.Red
        ) {
            Scaffold(backgroundColor = Color.Blue) {
                //...
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The background will be blue

3. Finally, if you set the content's background like below...

```
setContent {
    YourAppTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = Color.Red
        ) {
            Scaffold(
                backgroundColor = Color.Blue
            ) {
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.Green)) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will have a green background.

Comment: Hmm maybe I dont' get it because I am new. But even if I put the scaffold inside a surface, and give that surface a background color, it don't change. So what you are saying ( If I understand it correct) if I put a child into a mother, the childs color will also overwrite the mother ?

Comment: I added more details in my answer. Let me know if it's clear now.

Comment: Ok thanks again for taking your time. I do understand what you are explaining I just cant seem to get it to work. Inside my scaffold content. I call another cutom composable that inded has a fillMaxSize() I also give this composable a background(AppColors.mBlue). Inside that custom composable i have 3 cards() that have not fillMaxSize. So for my understanding the entire background of the scaffold should be Mblue, but its not its still white ?

Comment: Ok I got it working now. You where correct, and well explained. I had a custom comp() where inside I set the surface background, but after that I had a column, wich I did not set the background. That was the problem. Thanks so much

Comment: @michael-christensen Please accept the answer so it is clear to others the proposed solution worked.

Comment: @Code Poet Thanks I did now, I am also kinda new to stackoverflow apperently I only gave it a thumbs up before. But now I also accepted the answer, thanks for pointing that out.